# How can you see the difference between a melamine plate and a plate with a melamine coating?

Tags: material-science

How can you see the difference between a melamine plate and a plate with a melamine coating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break the plate open and look inside, is the simplest answer.

If you know the acoustic properties of melamine you can probe the plate with sonar. Or you could use x-rays (or another more appropriate wavelength) to image through the plate and look for a material change.

If you know the density of the melamine you could do Archimedes' test, comparing the weight and volume of the plate to see if it's all melamine or if it's composite. You could also measure the heat capacity of the plate, if you know the thermal properties of melamine, and compare that.

I suppose with the right setup you could use chemical methods - burning, dissolving with acid, etc. - or perhaps spectroscopy of some sort. And there are certainly other methods I don't even know about. But this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Oldest known solution: measure its density and see if it agrees with the density of melamine.

Indirect measurements increase accuracy as described on the following page:

http://www.math.nyu.edu/~crorres/Archimedes/Crown/CrownIntro.html